# ./openmw-launcher.i686: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I've been trying to install OpenMorroWind for about 2 days now and this error just keeps popping up whenever i try to launch it.
I've tried installing the LibQtGui.so.4 with apt install, but somehow it apparently still doesn't exist. I'm able to search for, and find the file in question and yet somehow the command line can't seem to find it. I've tried looking for a solution online but most of them just tell you to do "apt-get install libqtgui4" which i've already done. Thanks in advance for any help <3

Comment: Do you have installed [`libqtgui4` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=LibQtGui.so.4&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any)?

Comment: yes , i installed it yesterday and also tried restarting my laptop

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32-bit `openmw` on 64-bit OS, then it seems you should install 32-bit Qt-library with

```
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4:i386
```

---

Also I'm sorry, but Ubuntu packages have [`openmw*` packages in repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=OpenMw).

You can install them with

```
sudo apt-get install openmw-launcher
```